# Match nodes with and without a relationship in Neo4j

Tags: graph, neo4j, cypher

I am using the sample movie graph which comes with a Neo4j installation.

I would like to get an actor (by name), roles which he acted in movies and all other movies (which he isn't yet connected to).

The closest I can get is something like the following, but the actor, roles and actedInMovies repeat as many times as there are otherMovies.

```
MATCH (actor{name:'Bill Paxton'})-[roles:ACTED_IN]->(actedInMovies), (otherMovies:Movie)
WHERE NOT (actor)-[:ACTED_IN]->(otherMovies)
RETURN actor, roles, actedInMovies, otherMovies
```

How can I get only one result for the actor, roles for corresponding movie, and all other movies?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

how about a slightly different approach First get all of the movies that Bill Paxton acted in and then with that collection of movies find all of the movies that aren't in it.  Then return Bill Paxton, the collection of movies he acted in and the collection of movies he did not act in (i.e. the remainder)

```
MATCH (actor:Person {name:'Bill Paxton'})-[r:ACTED_IN]->(acted:Movie) 
with actor, collect(acted) as acted_in_movies, collect(r) as roles
MATCH (other:Movie)
WHERE none (acted in acted_in_movies where acted = other) 
RETURN actor.name, acted_in_movies, roles, collect(other) as other_movies
```

Updated query to reflect the data set I tested it with.  Added the collection of role names and change the movie nodes to titles for the result set.

```
MATCH (actor {name:'Bill Paxton'})-[r:ACTS_IN]->(acted) 
with actor, collect(acted) as acted_in_movies, collect(acted.title) as acted_titles, collect(r.name) as roles
MATCH (other:Movie)
WHERE none (acted in acted_in_movies where acted = other) 
RETURN actor.name, acted_titles, roles, collect(other.title) as other_movies
```

Comment: I get 0 rows with that query?

Comment: Nope, it's ACTED_IN for sure

Comment: and this? MATCH (actor {name:'Bill Paxton'})-[roles:ACTED_IN]->(acted) return actor, collect(acted) as acted_in_movies  It has to be a data thing.  I used the movie data set here http://neo4j.com/developer/example-data/#_the_data_sets and tried the original query but I has to change the ACTED_IN to ACTS_IN for it to return rows

Comment: This is good. Sorry, the ,mistake was that actor nodes are labeled as :Person, not :Actor...

Comment: I edited your original answer as with :Person lable, and it is almost what i needed, the roles are missing ...